# Dynamically add UIImage into UITextView or UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimage

I have a UIScrollView with a UITextView inside. At the bottom of the screen I have a button that takes the user to a detail view where they can sign their name. Once they are done, the app saves the signature as a .png and I'd like that .png to show up in either the UITextView or below it in UIScrollView.

I know I can add a UIImage placeholder, but there is no limit to how many signatures can be added. How can I add a UIImage each time a signature is added?

Comment: So are you wanting to create a new UIImage every time the user adds a signature? And will that UIImage replace a previous one?

Comment: @hw731 - Yes to the first question. No to the second. Each signature will be added underneath the previous signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **data model** should keep track of each user, the number of signatures they have provided, and the URLs of the png images (in the app documents folder or iCloud).

With this information, you can simply add `UIImageView`s via `addSubview:` and set the image via `setImage:`. Use `imageWithContentsOfFile:` to create the image.